# Order of unrelated lines of VBA code breaks

Tags: string, excel, vba, date, format

I need help understanding why the order of two particular lines of code matters. To me it just seems that the one line has got nothing to do with the other.

I'm running Windows 7 and Excel 2007 on a nice strong computer with swedish as system and application language.

This code doesn't work (breaks on the second line):

```
Cells(2, 2).Value = "Hi"

Cells(4, 4).Value = Format(Date , "Short date")
```

This however works:

```
Cells(4, 4).Value = Format(Date , "Short date")

Cells(2, 2).Value = "Hi"
```

The first piece of code seemed to work just fine and then all of a sudden it stopped working. It's kind of worrying since the Excel sheet is a "production sheet" and I'm not going to be the one using it.

Many thanks in advance

Mugs.

Comment: I think we'll need more code to provide context.

Comment: "How important the order of code is" - Code runs one line at a time, not all at once. To be a little more precise, two lines which have nothing to do with eachother should be able to be flipped without changing operation. In the case above, I can't see anything that would fail in the 1st one if the 2nd one doesn't fail. Are you sure nothing else changed? Because something else changed.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the macro is in a chain of macros. I don't know if this matters though.

Comment: Ok, I just figured it out. I'm stupid. That's the main problem. The problem with the code was that when I change the value of Cells(2, 2) I run another macro with (ByVal Target As Range)

Many thanks for you response. I think it made me question my code and find the solution.